# How to prove a string is decidable (formal languages)

Tags: decidable

I am trying to prove if string in machine L(M) is decidable and i am not able to find appropriate results for that. could anyone help me in explaining some example on this.

The scenario that I am trying is I have a two strings and S1 is a subset of S2 such that show machine L(M) is decidable

Comment: Can you please give the **exact** problem statement? By paraphrasing, you have lost the important information we need to help you. Also, you might have more success if you post this question on our sister site [Math.SE] since it is more of a math problem than a programming one.

Comment: Let M be a dfa. To show that it is decidable if L(M) contains s1 and s2 where s1 is subset of s2, s1 is not empty and s1 is not equal to s2.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I have just posted the same in Mathematics stackexchange. hope to see some ideas there.

Comment: Did you create a separate account on Math.SE? Since you didn't use your existing Stack Exchange account, I cannot easily find your post over there.

Comment: Oh I just posted as a guest in there. Please find the same on this link. 
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/960202/how-to-prove-a-string-in-machine-m-is-decidable